# Displaying datetime in client timezone in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, timezone

I've a blog created in ASP.NET MVC framework. How I can display the article posted date, comments posted date in client's datetime currently they are displayed in server datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [getTimezoneOffset](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp) method to adjust date into client timezone using javascript.